# How to access DynamoDB local using DynamoDB JavaScript Shell?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I have set up a Dynamodb in my local. 
I can access it using **`cmd`** with commands like:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

And I get the list of the tables I have in my local
But when I tried to access it through the **DynamoDB JavaScript Shell**,
I get this result:

[image]

How I can access my Dynamodb local through DynamoDB JavaScript Shell?

> Update: Below is the code that returns the error in the image above.

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'my-table',
    Limit: 10
};
dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

Comment: Can you list all of the commands you have done so far. The one put above you said worked. What is the one or ones that failed?

Comment: @Kirk, I have added the code above

Comment: Are you specifying in the connection string of the code to connect to localhost:8000? Did you do the aws configure to set up the credentials and everything?

Comment: @Kirk, yeah, I did the aws configure. where I can specify the localhost:8000?

Comment: as I mentioned I can access it using the terminal but using the Dynamodb shell I get the above result

Comment: Can you print the output you get from running `dynamodb.listTables` inside the shell?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the endpoint URL to the DynamoDB constructor:

`var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({endpoint: 'http://localhost:8000' })`

[Dynamodb constructor docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#constructor-property)